# Solr- multivalued date field, range queries to match "any"/"count"?

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm using Solr as part of a property booking engine- my entries have a multivalued date field which stores the dates that the property is already booked, and thus, not available. I want to be able to query against this, and return entries that have no dates within the window specified.

I'm half way there- but right now Solr appears to be returning the entry if it has even one free date- I want it to only return entries that are *totally* empty within the range. Example of my entity:

```
<doc>
    <arr name="DateBlockDates">
        <date>2011-02-25T00:00:00Z</date>
        <date>2011-02-26T00:00:00Z</date>
        <date>2011-02-27T00:00:00Z</date>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

The query works great in this instance:

```
-DateBlockDates:[2011-02-25T00:00:00Z TO 2011-02-27T00:00:00Z]
```

Because the entity does have date blocks for every one of those days. However, when I run:

```
-DateBlockDates:[2011-02-25T00:00:00Z TO 2011-02-28T00:00:00Z]
```

The entity gets returned, because it doesn't have an entry for 2011-02-28.

To put my question into old-school SQL, I want to do a "count(DateBlockDates) = 0". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best solution I've come up with- not using a range for the date query, and instead using:

```
-DateBlockDates:"2011-02-25T00:00:00.000Z"
AND -DateBlockDates:"2011-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"
AND -DateBlockDates:"2011-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"
AND -DateBlockDates:"2011-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"
```

It's messy, but it works. Thankfully I'm going to be dealing with relatively small date ranges, so the query won't get too long. But if there is a better solution out there I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Hi Alastair, did you ever find a better solution to this? I'm trying to store multiple datetime values and be able to do a date range search over them.

Comment: consider transforming date/time to UTC (if not already) then to an integer value representing the seconds since the epoch. Should allow for more empirical date range queries