# Filtering on two different dates on the same filter in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

In Solr, if you have an indexed piece of data, and within that data you had a set of date values, how can you query against the index and ask for events between X and Y date?

For example, if I have a list of Event Venues, each with dozens of events (single, all day, or multi-day), how would you construct the filter to return venues whos events are between the start and end date specified in a search?

Right now, if I search in a form and submit it through to Solr, the query string looks like this:

```
&fq=dm_event_start_date\:value:["2013-01-04T05:00:00Z" TO *]
&fq=dm_event_end_date\:value:[* TO "2013-01-08T05:00:00Z"]
&fq=bm_tickets_left\:value:"TRUE"
```

What I really want to ask for are events that occur or start on January 4th, don't last beyond January 8th, AND still have tickets left.

I feel like what I am getting in return is any event that either falls between the two dates, or has tickets available- not necessarily matching the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the date field values needs to be out of the quote in the range query e.g. :-

```
&fq=dm_event_start_date:value:[2013-01-04T05:00:00Z TO *]
&fq=dm_event_end_date:value:[* TO 2013-01-08T05:00:00Z]
&fq=bm_tickets_left:value:true
```

Also the `bm_tickets_left` needs to be just the string value.

Comment: This seems like a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914083/solr-multivalued-date-field-range-queries-to-match-any-count - If you're storing a date in one mysql record (start to end), and it is indexed in Solr as two fields, how do you ensure they are connected when queried?